# I want to force users to enter a contact role prior to saving new opportunities. Can this be done?

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

I have a basic opportunity object and would like to require sales teams to enter at least one Contact Role in order to save the Opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that if you build a custom UI for entering Opportunity data, such as a Lightning component or Visualforce page, and completely replaced the out-of-the-box user interface. (This would be a pretty large project).

Because Opportunity Contact Role is a child of Opportunity, you cannot use Validation Rules or Apex triggers to require OCRs on the save of Opportunity, as they can't even be created until the Opportunity saves.